# PHP LDAP bind state through pages

Tags: php, active-directory, ldap

I am creating a small PHP system where the users can edit their active directory details.

The first page is a login page which redirects to the main page where the users can edit their details.

On the login page, I use [`ldap_bind`](http://php.net/ldap_bind) to authenticate the users which on success redirects the to the main page. Now, I do not want to pass the password of the user through sessions for security reasons.

How do I pass the bind state to the other pages in the system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the same connection to the server. Once the authorization state has been established by the bind request on the connection, that authorization state is used by the connection until the next request bind or the connection is dropped.